# Why is one sleepy/tired after playing basketball but not after running?

Tags: running, calories, gym, exercise-technique, brain

One may sleep very well last night. But after playing basketball(40 minutes, mild), he may become very sleepy.

That is probably because his brain needs more oxygen. But why is he much better after running 5 miles quickly? Running seems more sensitive to oxygen and it depletes more calories.

How to reduce the level of fatigue after playing basketball?

Comment: I think this question needs to be revised with more details about the situation. Who is he? How old is he? Does this happen every single time he plays basketball? Is "he" a competitive runner? What is his diet like? Is "he" running one day and playing basketball the next day? or is he running and playing basketball in the same day? Reason why I am wanting more details about this question is because I might be able to answer it being that My son is 17 years old competes long distance running he runs 10 miles and does not get winded he also plays basketball and doesn't get fatigued.

Answer (score 2):

I find that basketball fatigues me much quicker and recovery takes longer than running.

Running a 5k/10k is one long continuous activity at a moderate pace; unless of course you're competing in a race.

Basketball is full of starts, stops, cutting, jumping, sprinting and more.

Playing basketball forces a certain intensity (a tie game, sprinting back on defense, diving for a loose ball) that solo running may not (always) provide.